# Byte changes magically

Tags: java, enums, byte

I got an enum where every enum constant has one byte and one object of an interface (via lambda)

```
//...
public enum InstructionSet {
  //...
  INSTRUCTION_HALT((byte) 0xF0, (ticksSinceStart) -> {
      return halt(ticksSinceStart);
  });


  private final byte opCode;
  private MicroOperationPlan plan;

   private InstructionSet(byte opCode, MicroOperationPlan opPlan) {
       this.opCode = opCode;
       this.plan = opPlan;
   }

   //...

   public byte getOpByte() {
       return this.opCode;
   } 
}
```

Now I got an debug output in my main method. No more code is executed BEFORE in my main method. The byte 'opCode' is final in my enum, so it cannot be changed.
The debug instruction:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(InstructionSet.INSTRUCTION_HALT.getOpByte()));

  //...
}
```

What I think should be printed into terminal: f0

What is printed into terminal: fffffff0

When I do not convert it to a hex-string, it still prints -16 into terminal, what is the decimal equivalent to fffffff0.

What happened?

Comment: You are converting Integer to Hex String, but you start off with a Byte.  It is extending your byte 0xF0 to an Integer of 0xFFF0 (or 0xFFFFFFF0).  Try to use a BYTE conversion to Hex.

Comment: It looks like `java.lang.Byte` does not have any methods for string conversion in a non-decimal radix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A byte, `1111 0000`, was extended to four bytes with the default, sign-inheriting method: `1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 0000` and then converted to hex string.

As JB Nizet pointed out, bytes are signed in Java, so a `byte` cannot have a value above 127; if the high bit is set, they are negative.

Therefore, you must undo the default sign-inheriting behavior, e.g.

```
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(InstructionSet.INSTRUCTION_HALT.getOpByte() & 0xFF))
```

Comment: I thought of this possibility, but I couldnt imagine a reason. The code works, if the byte is less than 0x10 (so 0x0-0xF). Why should java fill the number 240 to -16 when it is converted to integer but fill 0x3 to 3 (so with 0000'0000 bytes?)

Comment: @Cydhra bytes are signed in Java. There is no byte with value 240. bytes go from -128 to 127.

Comment: Yeah, I understand. Thank you.

Comment: Do you know, whether I can extend the byte to an integer by filling with zeros?

Comment: You cannot treat a `byte` as unsigned in Java. There is no way. Whenever a `byte` has to be extended, it will be extended with `0` bits if the value is positive, and with `1` bits, if negative.